# How does String.Format work in this situation?

Tags: c#, string

I have a website where you can buy stuff, and we want to format the orderID that goes to our portal in certain way. I am using the `string.format` method to format it like this:

```
Portal.OrderID = string.Format( "{0}{1:0000000}-{2:000}", 
                                "Z",
                                this.Order.OrderID, 
                                "000");
```

So we want it to look like this basically `Z0545698-001`. My question is, if I am using `string.format` will it blow up if `this.Order.OrderID` is greater than **`7`** characters?

If so, how can I keep the same formatting (i.e. `Z` `1234567` `-` `000`) but have the first set of numbers (the 1-7) be a minimum of **`7`** (with any numbers less than 7 in length have leading `0`'s). And then have anything greater than **`7`** in length just extend the formatting so I could get an order number like `Z12345678-001`?

Comment: How about trying out? [Here is an example](http://ideone.com/1ASb7y).

Comment: Will it always be a 'Z'? If so, you'll get better performance by leaving the Z as part of the format string.

Comment: When all else fails, [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#NotesCustomFormatting). "If the number has more digits than there are digit placeholders to the left of the decimal point, the extra digits are copied to the result string immediately before the first digit placeholder."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I keep the same formatting (i.e. Z 1234567 - 000) but have the first set of numbers (the 1-7) be a minimum of 7 (with any numbers less than 7 in length have leading 0's). And then have anything greater than 7 in length just extend the formatting so I could get an order number like Z12345678-001?

Use exactly the code that you have, because that's what it does.

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't sure if there was a strict limit on the length that it would have to be. Thanks.

Comment: @Brett Which is why you can simply [try it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857950/how-does-string-format-work-in-this-situation/18857969?noredirect=1#comment27826183_18857950) and see for yourself.